# Add something before custom post type in permalink

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

How do I add for example "en" (for English) before custom post typ in Wordpress permalink?

For example:

> http://example.com/en/post_type/postname

I've tried this plugin (http://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-permalinks/), but it only allows me to change permalink structure after the post type.

Comment: How do you want to use the `en` prefix inside the custom post type?

Comment: I have one post type for the English content and one for the Swedish content. Therefor I want to add the "en" before the post type in the permalinks for the English post type. Is that posaible?